# how do I give a div a responsive height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm stating to learn responsive design, but there's one thing I can't seem to figure out, so far...

Here's a working example: http://ericbrockmanwebsites.com/dev1/

I'd like the div element (contactBg) with text inside of it to come down to the bottom of the image to the left. Obviously I can do that by defining the height in px, but then that height is maintained when the rest of the window resizes instead of being fluid.

If there are any good articles out there you may know of that explains how to do this, that would be very helpful, thanks!

Here's the mark up:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span10 offset1">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span5">
                        <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo" />
                        <img src="images/store.jpg" alt="store" />
                    </div><!-- /span5 -->
                    <div class="span7">
                        <img src="images/portal.jpg" alt="portal">
                        <div class="contactBg">
                            Administration: Emma Jane Julien<br />
                            <a href="mailto:ej@emmajulien.com">ej@emmajulien.com</a>
                        </div><!-- /contactBg -->
                    </div><!-- /span7 -->
                </div><!-- /row-fluid -->
            </div><!-- /container-fluid -->
        </div><!-- /span10 offset1 -->
    </div> <!-- /row-fluid -->
```

And here's the css:

```
   body {
        background: url(../images/3D2A1698A177AF9B71_218.png) repeat;
    }

    img {
        max-width:100%;
        padding-bottom:1%;
    }

     .container-fluid {
        background:#fff;
        padding: 1%;
    }

      .row-fluid {
        width: 100%;
        *zoom: 1;
 }
      .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 30px;
        margin-left: 1%;
        *margin-left: 2.709239449864817%;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
           -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
}

      .row-fluid .span10 {
        width: 82.87292817679558%;
        *width: 82.81973668743387%;
      }

      .row-fluid .span7 {
        width: 58.06353591160195%;
        *width: 57.12912895262725%;
      }

      .row-fluid .span5 {
        width: 40.93646408839753%;
        *width: 40.00205712942283%;
      }
      .row-fluid .span4 {
        width: 31.491712707182323%;
        *width: 31.43852121782062%;
      }

    .contactBg {
        background: #282624;
        padding: 3%;
        max-width:100%;
        height:auto;
    }
```

Comment: What about defining a font-size in percentages?

Comment: @kleinfreund Oh that's clever. I'll try it out and let you know!

Comment: @kleinfreund actually doesn't work great as the % / em is in reference to the default font-size, not the area it's in, I think...

Comment: This is true if you previously have designed the font-size. You might get in tough with media-queries then. They would allow to adjust the font-size according to specific screen sizes.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I know this is a little late to the party but you could use viewport units

From caniuse.com:

Viewport units: vw, vh, vmin, vmax - CR
Length units representing 1% of the viewport size for viewport width (vw), height (vh), the smaller of the two (vmin), or the larger of the two (vmax).

Support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

```css
div {
/* 25% of viewport */
  height: 25vh;
  width: 15rem;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div>responsive height</div>
```

Comment: nice and clean example !

Comment: Perfect this helps alot,  i am working on custom slider with responsive image.

Answer (score 6):

For the height of a div to be responsive, it must be inside a parent element with a defined height to derive it's relative height from.

If you set the height of the container holding the image and text box on the right, you can subsequently set the heights of its two children to be something like 75% and 25%.

However, this will get a bit tricky when the site layout gets narrower and things will get wonky. Try setting the padding on .contentBg to something like 5.5%.

My suggestion is to use Media Queries to tweak the padding at different screen sizes, then bump everything into a single column when appropriate.

Comment: this is getting closer, but there's still the issue of defining the height of the parent element by px, as you can see on the example site: http://ericbrockmanwebsites.com/dev1/ now when the rest of the page resizes, that element (obviously) maintains it's size.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the BEST solution, but it does appear to work. Instead of using the background color, I'm going to just embed an image of the background, position it relatively and then wrap the text in a child element and position it absolute - in the centre.