# Make HTML element fill rest of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I have the following HTML.

```
<body>
    <nav>..</nav>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row' id='header'>
            ...
        </div>
        <div class='row' id='content'>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My aim is to have the `header` remain constant height, while the `content` fill the rest of the page (I have a Highchart in there). I have tried to use the information here: [how do I give a div a responsive height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714744/how-do-i-give-a-div-a-responsive-height) and here: http://codethatworks.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/responsive-full-height-columns-using.html and here [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space?answertab=active#tab-top) - but with no luck.

My basic understanding is that I set the body height to `100%`, and the `header` height to say 25% and the `content` to say `75%`. Is the `nav` confusing things here?

Please note that I am using Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Where is that `<nav>` supposed to go?  I mean, if the header is 25% and the content is 75%, where did you want the nav to fit?

Answer (score 1):

It's not just the `body` you need to set to 100% height, it's all the parents of those two 'rows'.  So in your case, `html, body, .container`.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body > .container {
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}

#header {
  height: 25%;
  background: yellow;
}

#content {
  height: 75%;
  background: red;
}
```

If you don't set your `nav` to be positioned absolutely, then it'll cause a scrollbar as it's pushing the content down and making the total height more than 100%.

[Demo here!](http://jsbin.com/iNOcikaC/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the viewport percentage. See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SvHXB/3/)**

Relevant lines:

```
#header
{        
    height: 25vh;
    ...
}

#content
{    
    height:75vh;
    ...
}
```

In this case you don't have to set the height of body, html, etc. If you want it to fill the page without padding you would add:

```
body
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;    
}
```

See support [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

See [this answer](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) for more details.

For the `nav` element, you either need to make this absolutely positioned as suggested in other answers or give up some percentage of the page for the nav. E.g. make `content` height `65vh` and `nav` height `10vh`.